# F# Marshall structs with field of delegate type

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have a native C library and I want do some F# coding with it. The thing is I get exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: **Cannot marshal field 'log' of type
>   'LoggingModel': There is no marshaling support for this type.**
>   at
>   System.StubHelpers.ValueClassMarshaler.ConvertToNative(IntPtr dst,
>   IntPtr src, IntPtr pMT, CleanupWorkList& pCleanupWorkList)
>   at
>   FSI_0009.Initialize(ComponentOverrideFlags flags, LoggingModel&
>   loggingModel, ThreadingModel& threadingModel, SchedulingModel&
>   schedulingModel, IntPtr memoryModel)
>   at
>   .$FSI_0011.main@() 
>   in
>   D:\dev_p\f#\FunBindings\FunExample\Environment.fs:line 16 Stopped due
>   to error

Here the code:

```
module Interop

[<CLSCompliant(true); Flags>]
type LogTarget =
    | None = 0
    | Console = 1
    | Trace = 2
    | Custom = 4 

[<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
type LogCallback = delegate of LogTarget * string * string * nativeint -> unit

[<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
type ReleaseCallback = delegate of nativeint -> unit

[<Struct>]
type LoggingModel =
    val mutable targets : LogTarget
    val mutable log : LogCallback
    val mutable deleteModel : ReleaseCallback
    val mutable userparam : IntPtr

[<DllImport("CLIBRARY.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "txInitialize")>]
[<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)>]
extern int Initialize(ComponentOverrideFlags flags, LoggingModel& loggingModel, ThreadingModel& threadingModel, SchedulingModel& schedulingModel, IntPtr memoryModel)

module Environment

let initialize =
    let mutable loggingModel = new LoggingModel()
    let mutable threadingModel = new ThreadingModel()
    let mutable schedulingModel = new SchedulingModel()
    Initialize(ComponentOverrideFlags.None, &loggingModel, &threadingModel, &schedulingModel, IntPtr.Zero)
```

Basically, I get the aforementioned error when I try to execute "initialize" function in interactive.

I would really appreciate any help.

**Update:** I've checked the code a bit more and noticed that outside of the interactive console it seems to be working, without failing with exceptions. I need to provide a bit more coverage for CLibrary to be sure. Meanwhile, if there anybody who knows what could cause this exception and how it could be prevented, I would really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `delegate of LogTarget * string * string * nativeint -> unit` declares a delegate where the arguments are curried. (This doesn't really make sense to me either since `a * b` normally represents a tuple.)

The subtly different `delegate of (LogTarget * string * string * nativeint) -> unit` declares a delegate with tupled arguments which would be compatible with a native function.

You can see this difference if you try and assign a .NET method to two different delegate types:

```
type Curried = delegate of int * int -> int
type Tupled = delegate of (int * int) -> int

//let a = new Curried (Math.Max) // doesn't compile
let b = new Tupled (Math.Max) // works
```

Comment: Sorry, Tim, it didn't help. I will edit question with full exception info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `[<MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)>]` to LoggingModel?

```
[<Struct>]
type LoggingModel =
    val mutable targets : LogTarget
    [<MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)>]
    val mutable log : LogCallback
    [<MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)>]
    val mutable deleteModel : ReleaseCallback
    val mutable userparam : IntPtr
```

IL code without this attribute is:

```
// Fields
.field public class Interop.LogCallback log
```

but with this attribute is:

```
// Fields
.field public marshal(Func) class Interop.LogCallback log
```

Without `marshal(Func)`/MarshalAs attribute the delegate cannot be marshalled even with the UnmanagedFunctionPointer attribute. Cannot test it with a native library though.

Comment: Yes, I did tried that before. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Same error.

Comment: Have you also tried to add corresponding MarshalAs to function arguments in `type LogCallback = delegate of (LogTarget * string * string * nativeint) -> unit`, e.g. `<MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I4)>]target:LogTarget`? Probably enum doesn't have default marshalling.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried and issue stays same. Exception still points on the log field.